# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP , The server encountered an internal error ()

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I've created a custom tag but when I use the the following Exception occured:-

```
An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
  LoopTextTag cannot be resolved to a type
   <body>
     <center>
         <ct:loopText times="5">
            <h3>Loop Text!</h3>
        </ct:loopText>
```

StackTrace:

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:423)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

My LoopTaxtTag class as follow:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
 import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent;
 import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;


public class LoopTextTag extends BodyTagSupport {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int mTimes = 0;
private BodyContent mBodyContent;

public void setTimes(int pTimes) {
    mTimes = pTimes;
}


public void setBodyContent(BodyContent pBodyContent) {
    mBodyContent = pBodyContent;
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    if (mTimes > 1) {
        return EVAL_BODY_TAG;
    } else {
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public int doAfterBody() throws JspException {
    if (mTimes > 1) {
        mTimes--;
        return EVAL_BODY_TAG;
    } else {
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}


public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    try {
        if (mBodyContent != null) {
            mBodyContent.writeOut(mBodyContent.getEnclosingWriter());
        }
    } catch (IOException pIOEx) {
        throw new JspException("Error: " + pIOEx.getMessage());
    }
    return EVAL_PAGE;
}
}
```

my index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page import="com.pt.LoopTextTag"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld" prefix="ct" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
< %@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld" prefix="ct" %>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <center>

        <ct:loopText times="5">
            <h3>Loop Text!</h3>
        </ct:loopText>

    </center>
</body>
```

a warning also raised by compiler:

```
The tag handler class for "ct:loopText" (LoopTextTag) was not found on the Java Build Path
```

Comment: where is the index.jsp

Comment: where you kept your tag library

Comment: you imported <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld" prefix="ct" %>
 2 times

Comment: i've no extra tag lib....only tag handler tld file is there..

Comment: why 2 times imported same one

Comment: yes but this added later,I've removed this but same prob..

Comment: warning says...the tag handler class for "ct:loopText" (LoopTextTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922785/i-got-the-error-htmlencodertag-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-on-defining-a-cust

Comment: no,I'm using Myeclipse...

Comment: try to add jarfile to build path

Comment: Which jar Should I add?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured out, the problem is in `index.jsp` at following line:

```
 < %@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld" prefix="ct" %>
```

`uri` here should match with `<uri>` tag mentioned in `tld` file. The `tld` file should be located at one of the following places where container would look for:

1. Directly inside WEB-INF
2. Directly inside a sub directory of WEB-INF
3. WEB-INF/lib/jar/META-INF/
4. In a subdirectory of WEB-INF/lib/jar/META-INF/

Hope this helps